# jQuery function ready for new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function:

```
jQuery('#allForms td.edit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    addTextBox(jQuery(this));
});
```

doesn't work for new elements which I'm creating in this way:

```
var output = '<tr><td class="edit">'+values[0]+
    '</td><td class="edit">'+values[1]+
    '</td><td class="edit">'+values[2]+
    '</td><td class="edit">'+values[3]+
    '</td><td><a href="#" class="deleteForm">USUŃ</a></td></tr>';
formsList.find('tr:last').after(output);
addForm.find("input").val('');
```

When I click at newly added element nothing happens. When I click at elements which was loaded with website all works good.

Comment: You can use `jQuery(document).on("click", '#allForms td.edit', function(e){`

Comment: This is a duplicate of so, so many questions. Please use the search next time.

Comment: @Nit nevertheless, people still answer it before question is closed :)

Comment: Sorry, I searched but I didn't find nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events to dynamically added elements:

```
jQuery('#allForms').on('click','td.edit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
addTextBox(jQuery(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this

```
jQuery(document).on("click", '#allForms td.edit', function(e){
```